# Not showing page

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out why when I try and load this page all I get is a white screen. I'm not sure if I'm coding my application correctly. Can someone explain to me what I am doing incorrectly so I can fix it and have it show something in my browser at least.

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.header = """
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New York Yankees Starting Lineup/title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        """

        self.content = ""

        self.footer = """
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
     """

    def print_out(self):
        template = self.header + self.content + self.footer
        template = template.format(**locals())
        return template

class ContentPage(Page):
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_data = ''
        Page.__init__(self)
        self.player_data = '''
        <div>
        Name: + player_data.player_name
        Position: + player_data.position
        Bats: + player_data.bats
        Throws: + player_data.throws
        Batting Average: + player_data.avg
        Home Runs: + player_data.hr
        </div>'''

    def print_out(self):
        return self.header + self.content + self.player_data + self.footer
```

UPDATE: I'm still struggling with this issue. Is there anyone that can help me figure out what's going on and how to fix it? Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.content` is initialized to an empty string, and is never changed; `self.player_data` is possibly what you wish to see, but that is not used anywhere (although its name appears in the string assigned to `self.player_data`).

One solution would be to assign to `self.content` instead of `self.player_data` in the `__init__` for `ContentPage`; `self.player_data` looks like it should be the information *about* a player, and not the template for displaying that data.

Comment: How can I tell the content to display the player_data then?